# Extend SubSonic's IQueryable Structure (via LINQ?)

Tags: linq, subsonic3, iqueryable

I'm working on a project that groups data by a "customer id". When the user logs in, they're limited to that customer and that customer only.

I'm working with SubSonic3, and what I've got looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Foo> FindFoo(int userID, string searchText, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    return from item in Foo.GetPaged(pageIndex, pageSize)
           where (item.Name.Contains(searchText) ||   
                  item.Description.Contains(searchText)) &&
                  item.CustomerID == CurrentCustomerID()
                  select new Models.Foo(item);
}
```

What I'd like to do is abstract away the item.CustomerID line, because that's going to happen for *every* query, without fail, so it would be simpler (and more secure) to do it in one place and guarantee it'll happen everywhere.

So, my question is: can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: I hope you realise you are going to end up with a case sensitive search with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as subsonic generated classes are partial you can add some interface to them... Just create you're interface with CustomerID property (for example name it `ICusomerEntity`) and make partial for any of generated classes that will apply this interface to them... then just use the generic subsonic methods to rerieve `ICustomerEntity`, not the specific class..

For example you can make generic method called GetCustomerEntity with constraint `T:ICustomerEntity` which will return IQueriable with a bascic query comparing CustomerId with the one of logged user..

Hope it helps...